# How can I get the first three digits and compare for output?

Tags: java, switch-statement

The code is running, the problem is I can not get an exact output. I want to get the person's phone number and take the first three digits, and compare this with the exact telco. So far I got this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class lab03_ex03 {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int number;
    int n=3;
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter your phone number: ");
    number=input.nextInt();
    int b=Integer.parseInt((""+number).substring(0,n));
    if(b==013) {
      String me="TM";
    }
    switch(me) {
      case "TM":
        System.out.println("Answer: The phone number is a TM number.");
        break;
      case "Celcom":
        System.out.println("Answer: The phone number is a Celcom number.");
        break;
      case "DiGi":
        System.out.println("Answer: The phone number is a DiGi number.");
        break;
      case "Maxis":
        System.out.println("Answer: The phone number is a Maxis number.");
        break;
      // default:
        // System.out.println("Its look like unvalid number :( . Please check again");
    }
  }
}
```

In this example, if the person inputs 013456789, then it will only take `013` and will say it is a DIGI number. But when I try to do it, it shows nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your snippet shouldn't compile. Check your copy-paste for errors, or otherwise edit the content of your question to accurately describe the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: Declare the String `me` outside of any loop/if statement and then set it's value inside the loop/if statement.

Comment: I changed it , it can run, if i initilize String me=""; but its not showing output

Comment: Hi, gautam, is it illigal to use String in a switch case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code not even compile.

```
  if(b==013)
    {
        String me="TM"; //scope of String variable me is inside if only
    }
    switch(me) // you can't use it here
```

Next case if you use `nextInt()`, your input `013456789` will become `13456789`.

Also you should keep in mind that leading `0` will ignore if you use `int` to represent them.

You should correct your code as follows to correct above mention mistakes.

```
 String number;
 int n = 3;
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.print("Please enter your phone number: ");
 number = input.nextLine();
 String b = number.substring(0, n);
 String me=null;
 if (b.equals("013")) {
    me = "TM";
 }
 switch (me) {
   case "TM":
     System.out.println("Answer: The phone number is a TM number.");
     break;
   case "Celcom":
     System.out.println("Answer: The phone number is a Celcom number.");
     break;
   case "DiGi":
     System.out.println("Answer: The phone number is a DiGi number.");
     break;
   case "Maxis":
     System.out.println("Answer: The phone number is a Maxis number.");
     break;         
}
```

Comment: @farhanakonka Change `switch (b)` to `switch (me)` an make sure that `String` is declared within the correct context

Comment: *"You should correct your code as follows"* - yes, but why (yes I know, but it might be nice for the OP to know) - lead to water, don't hold there heads under it ;)

Comment: Thanks I follow your instruction , :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some serious flaws and I'm not really sure what you are trying to do. If you want to get the first three digits, try something like this.

```
String sNumber = in.nextLine();
sNumber = sNumber.substring(0,3);
int first3Digits = Integer.parseInt(sNumber);
```

Then, if you want to use this number in a switch to find the proper "telco number" do something like this.

```
switch(first3Digits){
case 013:
   System.out.println("DiGi");
   break;
//add more cases here
}
```

Comment: Will not work as leading zeroes are not considered as a part of the integer.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `013` will be taken as a Octal not decimal because decimal value don't start with Zero.

So `013` will be consider as decimal value 11 which you are comparing with b (value =13) So if condition is not getting invoked.

```
if(b==013) // value of b = 13 but value of 013 is 11
```